# How to get access on dynamically added Views with DataBinding

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-databinding

I have the following xml:

```
<layout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<ui.widget.expandable_layout.ExpandableLayout
    android:id="@+id/expandablelayout_devicemgmtitem_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:detail_layout="@layout/item_devicemgmt_details"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_devicemgmtitem_sn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</ui.widget.expandable_layout.ExpandableLayout>
```

In the `init` method of my ExpandableLayout class I add the detail_view that was passed by attribute like this:

```
final int eV = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.ExpandableLayout_detail_layout, -1);
expandableView =
                (eV != -1) ? LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(eV, this) : null;
```

When I bind the layout with:

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater
            .from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.item_devicemgmt, parent, false)
```

I only have access on the container and the textview. is it possible to get access to the views of `dynamic_layout` that were added dynamically with just one binding object?